# Vmware: to quiesce or not to quiesce

Tags: vmware-esxi

I'm fairly new to VMWare, and I'm working on some automation to snapshot a few VMWare VMs.

I was told I should power off, snapshot, and then power on the VM. However after reading about quiescing that seems like a really good option because:

If I'm turning off the VM I'm:

- not snapshotting Memory.
- just want to snapshot the disk.

When should I quiesce and when should I power off the VM for a snapshot?

Comment: You use snapshot to make a full backup ? as it's not the goal of a snapshot.

Comment: Hmmm yeah I've heard that before. What's the alternative? (Actually having a backup procedure?)

Comment: windows or Linux vm?

Comment: `Actually having a backup procedure?` Well, yeah...